# How to remove the custom css class in previous selected icon when user clicks on another icon in map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, icons

In my case leaflet map contains a list of icons, I want to highlight the selected icon among it by adding a custom class to selected icon. It worked but when user clicks on another icon both previously selected icon and new icon  highlighted as I didn't removed the added custom class when user clicks on another icon. Please guide me as I'm lost in thoughts on how to remove the class.

```
data.forEach((a) => {
  let l = L.geoJSON(a.geometry)._layers;
  const that = this;
  [l] = Object.keys(l).map((ob) => l[ob]);
  const icon = new utils.IconImage({
    className: "data-icon",
    iconAnchor: [15, 10],
    icon: a.asset_type.icon,
    id: parseInt(a.id, 10),
  });
  const coordinates = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a.geometry.coordinates));
  bounds.push(coordinates.reverse());
  l.setIcon(icon).addTo(this.map);
  l.on("click", (e) => {
    e.target._icon.classList.add("leaflet-edit-marker-selected");
  });
});
```

Comment: Save a reference to the last marker/icon that has been highlighted. The scope of that reference should be outside the loop.

Comment: You should do it without accessing private properties and/or methods which are indicated by underscore. Provide CodeSandbox with an example for a more precise answers.